# Different pattern to give input in console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner in .net and I made a simple console application and it's works. My problem is when I give input the input must be in new line
eg:

```
1
2
3
```

how I input like

```
1 2
3
```

I am using the following code

```
int a, b, c,d;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers:");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            d = a + b + c;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum:" + d);
```

Comment: You could use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to split each line you read with `Console.ReadLine()` by whitespace and convert the array members individually if there's more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an input parser... ReadLine, split the resulting string by space character and feed each segment into int converter and sum them.

Example given below is taking advantage of Linq which is a bit functional and allow chaining something like the token array resulting from the split and performs operations on each of its elements. I.e. `Select(...)` is basically a map function that will apply `Convert.ToInt32` to each elements in the token array and then pipe that into the `Aggregate` function that memoize the result so far (starting from 0 and keep adding the next element in the now converted int token array ... represented by `s + t` where `s` is current memoized seed and `t` is the current token in the iteration.)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = Console.ReadLine();
        var tokens = str.Split(' ');
        var result = tokens.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t)).Aggregate(0, (s, t) => s + t);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

For completeness sake... This second version should be more resistant to error:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 or more numbers separated by space in between. I.e. 1 2\nAny non numerical will be treated as 0:");
        var str = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, expecting 1 or more numbers separated by space in betwen. I.e. 5 6 8 9");
        }
        else
        {
            var tokens = str.Split(' ');
            var result = tokens
                .Select(t =>
                {
                    int i;
                    if (int.TryParse(t, out i))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Valid Number Detected: {0}", i);
                    };
                    return i;
                })
                .Aggregate(0, (s, t) => s + t);
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of all numbers is {0}", result);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this he could get an exception

Comment: Considering the question, I think it would be best to explain the Linq methods a bit.

Comment: Agree, he could get exceptions, but that's beside the point ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to accept a single line of input as a string and then process it. For example:

```
//Read line, and split it by whitespace into an array of strings
//1 2    
string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split();
//Parse element 0
int a = int.Parse(tokens[0]);

//Parse element 1
int b = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
```

One issue with this approach is that it will fail (by throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException/ FormatException`) if the user does not enter the text in the expected format. If this is possible, you will have to validate the input.

For example, with `regular expressions`:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();

// If the line consists of a sequence of digits, followed by whitespaces,
// followed by another sequence of digits (doesn't handle overflows)
if(new Regex(@"^\d+\s+\d+$").IsMatch(line))
{
   ...   // Valid: process input
}
else
{
   ...   // Invalid input
}
```

Alternatively:

Verify that the input splits into exactly 2 strings.
Use int.`TryParse` to attempt to parse the strings into numbers.

Here's an exmaple :

```
 class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0,
            b = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers:");
            var readLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (readLine != null)
            {
                // If the line consists of a sequence of digits, followed by whitespaces,
                // followed by another sequence of digits (doesn't handle overflows)
                if (new Regex(@"^\d+\s+\d+$").IsMatch(readLine))
                {
                    string[] tokens = readLine.Split();
                    //Parse element 0
                    a = int.Parse(tokens[0]);

                    //Parse element 1
                    b = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers");
                }
            }
            var c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var d = a + b + c;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum:" + d);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Console.ReadLine() which reads the whole line.

Documentation:

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return (hexadecimal 0x000d), a line feed (hexadecimal 0x000a), or the value of the Environment.NewLine property. The returned string does not contain the terminating character(s).

You can read whole line and then process it, for example with String.Split method.